# Capistrano, Rails, PostgreSQL Master-slaves replications making it hard to add additional tables to slaves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano

I have build a document-management system which consist of a content-management Rails application (for writing and managing docs, users and other content) and an End-User Rails application (for reading, searching etc.).

The content-management app is on a server for it self and I have a couple of end-user servers to ensure high availability (a requirement). The end-user servers acts as slaves to the content-management server (PostgreSQL master/slave replication).

This works great up until now that a new feature is required. End users should be able to generate pdfs of containing user selected documents. Now this in it self is no problem - the system should handle a large amount of docs so I've added a Sidekiq worker to do the PDF generation. But here comes the tricky part:
How can I add state to my end-user apps so that I can inform the user when the pdf is finished generating. In a perfect world I'd add a new model, say PDFPrintJob, which has a status attribute which I could inspect via a controller show action. But the problem is, that all end-user apps are on a read only database due to the master/slave situation.

So how should I fix this? Is there a better way of structuring the servers that would enable me to have additional tables on the slaves which are writeable?
I would be happy if the database servers could do the heavy lifting of keeping content synced.

I'm running Rails4 on JRuby 1.7.x and PostgreSQL 9.2

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the status of the job on Sidekiq with a plugin like `sidekiq-status`. At the very minimum you could do some polling in JavaScript to grab the status of your job. If you want to get fancy you could do server-side events using Rails 4.

Here's the portion that shows how to use the store and retrieve part of each Sidekiq job.

https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status

> Retrieving status
>
> Query for job status any time later:
>
> ```
> job_id = MyJob.perform_async(*args)
> # :queued, :working, :complete or :failed , nil after expiry (30 minutes)
> status = Sidekiq::Status::status(job_id)
> Sidekiq::Status::queued?   job_id
> Sidekiq::Status::working?  job_id
> Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id
> Sidekiq::Status::failed?   job_id
> ```
>
> Tracking progress, saving and retrieveing data associated with job
>
> ```
> class MyJob
>   include Sidekiq::Worker
>   include Sidekiq::Status::Worker # Important!
>
>   def perform(*args)
>     # your code goes here
>
>     # the common idiom to track progress of your task
>     at 5, 100, "Almost done"
>
>     # a way to associate data with your job
>     store vino: 'veritas'
>
>     # a way of retrieving said data
>     # remember that retrieved data is always is String|nil
>     vino = retrieve :vino
>   end
> end
>
> job_id = MyJob.perform_async(*args)
> data = Sidekiq::Status::get_all job_id
> data # => {status: 'complete', update_time: 1360006573, vino: 'veritas'}
> Sidekiq::Status::get     job_id, :vino #=> 'veritas'
> Sidekiq::Status::num     job_id #=> 5
> Sidekiq::Status::total   job_id #=> 100
> Sidekiq::Status::message job_id #=> "Almost done"
> Sidekiq::Status::pct_complete job_id #=> 5
> ```

Comment: This looks like a great approach.. I was looking the wrong place the entire time.. Thank you so much